# Pseudo code for Moravec Corner Detector

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, pseudocode

I am looking for some pseudo code for the Moravec corner detector.

I wish to have the pseudo code just as a means of understanding how the algorithm works.

Syntax of code is not important, however comments explaining what each component is doing would be useful. I am looking to gain a clear exposition of the algorithm.

Assume image im[y,x] indexed by y(row) and x(column).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick googling gives this page with description and pseudocode: http://kiwi.cs.dal.ca/~dparks/CornerDetection/moravec.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Moravec.java](http://code.google.com/p/jfeaturelib/source/search?q=moravec&origq=moravec&btnG=Search%20Trunk) implemented for [JFeatureLib](http://code.google.com/p/jfeaturelib/).